# Next.js JSON Retrieval - JSON Objects Issue

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript, next.js, coingecko

I am working on a simple crypto price tracker using coingecko API. My current code will not access any of the JSON objects from the API link and I get no errors or warnings indicating what the issue is: https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=bitcoin%2C%20ethereum%2C%20ripple&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false

However, for testing purposes if I use this API link from jsonplaceholder, it works absolutely fine: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

This is my code:

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {

//Does not work with this json url
// const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')

const res = await fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=bitcoin%2C%20ethereum%2C%20ripple&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false')
const data = await res.json();
const paths = data.map(coin => {
return {
  params: {id: coin.id}
}
})

return {
    paths,
    fallback: false
    }
}

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
const id = context.params.id; 

//Does not work with this json url
// const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + id )

const res = await fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=' + id + '%2C%20&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false/')

const data = await res.json();
console.log(data)

return {
    props: {coin: data}
  }
}

const Details = ({ coin }) => {
return(
   
     <div>
      <h1>Coin Page</h1>
      <h2>{ coin.name }</h2>
      <h2>{ coin.symbol }</h2>
    </div>
   )
}

export default Details;
```

As I have said I get no errors or warnings so any hep on troubleshooting this would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some problems in your code, you can check it out this version that works fine.

Here is the code sandbox that I used to reproduce your situation:
https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-star-55pyl?file=/pages/coins/%5Bid%5D.js:0-1221

You have to visit the url /bitcoin for example for it to work.

First of all I removed the "%2C%20" from the url because that represents and space and a comma and that's usefull when you have a list of currencies but not in this case.

Lastly in your component you get an array of coins and you should reference the first one (there is only one item).

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  //Does not work with this json url
  // const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')

  const res = await fetch(
    "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=bitcoin%2C%20ethereum%2C%20ripple&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false"
  );

  const data = await res.json();
  const paths = data.map((coin) => {
    return {
      params: { id: coin.id.toString() }
    };
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const id = context.params.id;

  //Does not work with this json url
  // const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + id )

  const res = await fetch(
    "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=" +
      id +
      "&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false"
  );

  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { coin: data }
  };
};

const Details = ({ coin }) => {
  console.log(coin);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Coin Page</h1>
      <h2>{coin[0].name}</h2>
      <h2>{coin[0].symbol}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Details;
```

[image: Captura CodeSandBox]